# 'Undefined function' error, but I don't even use it

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a function that can return a function which adjusts if an input value is in array. Here is the code:

```
function in = getArray(varargin)
%varargin must contain some 2D-arrays that define the border of range
%say,[0,1] [100,102]
    narginchk(1,inf);

    function result = isIn(value)
        len = size(varargin);
        for k = 1:len(1)
            arr = varargin(k);
            if (value >= arr(1)) && (value <= arr(2))
                result = 1;
                return;
            else 
                result = 0;
            end
        end
    end
    in = @isIn;
end
```

It's so odd that when I call it by `in = getArray([0,1]);in(10)` the error is as follows:

```
??? Undefined function 'ge' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in getArray/isIn (line 10)
            if (value >= arr(1)) && (value <= arr(2))
```

Can someone find something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `ge` is called when performing the `>=` operation. The error tries to tell you that you are not allowed to do a `>=` operation with a cell array as first operand.

As [Marc already mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16401943/296974), this problem stems from the fact that you access your `varargin` array - which is a cell array - using `()`, which makes the result be a cell array as well.

Instead, use `{}` as this will pick the contents out of the cell array and have the correct data type.

Comment: @ssj - Note that the debuggger would have made this clear. It is a good tool. Learn to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try indexing varargin using curly brackets, it's a cell array: `arr = varargin{k};`.